# Effect of spin on the deflection of a rigid body

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics, rigid-body-dynamics

Suppose an x-y coordinate axes is set on the ground,  then a spherical object is projected in the forward direction (the positive y direction) and while moving in this forward direction it also happens to be spinning about an axis through it's center of mass and pointing at some angles to the positive y-direction. 
Then up on impact does the ball get deflected at some positive angle to the x direction due to may be friction or the ball just having a velocity component in that direction?
If it does so why exactly does it happen?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

That certainly happens all summer long during baseball season.  A pitched ball thrown in the dirt often deflects sideways due to spin on the ball, especially for a curve ball.  It is due to friction between the ball and the ground.  The direction of deflection will be in the direction of the spin, assuming the ground is not so uneven to cause a significant deflection of its own.